# How to retrieve only the nodes from the path in Neo4J Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query of the following kind:

```
MATCH (u1:User{name:"user_name"}), (s1:Statement), s1-[:BY]->u1 
WITH DISTINCT s1,u1 
MATCH (s2:Statement), s2-[:BY]->u1, 
p=s1<-[:OF]-c-[:OF]->s2 
WHERE s1 <> s2 
WITH collect(p) AS coll, count(p) AS paths, s1, s2 
RETURN s1,s2,paths,coll 
ORDER BY paths DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```

Right now it returns a list of all the paths p in the `coll` variable. I want it to list only the nodes `c`. How to make this possible?

Maybe the query is not right, in this case, what I'm trying to do is to

1) Find all statements made by a user;

2) Find the nodes that connect those two statements;

3) Return those statements, which have the most nodes connecting them, ORDER BY DESC, including the names of the actual nodes that connect them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it at the moment, but you could try something like

```
MATCH (u:User {name:"user_name"})<-[:BY]-(s1)<-[:OF]-(c)-[:OF]->(s2)-[:BY]->(u)
RETURN s1, s2, collect(c) as connections 
ORDER BY length(connections) DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Great! This works fine after the edit I made. Please, let me know if using the <> operator is a good choice here. And also - in Neo4J interface is there a way that the (c) nodes are not shown in the graph?

Comment: I don't see an edit, did you edit my answer? If the query isn't right, could you update your question with some details? I assume it has to do with duplicates since you ask about `<>`, but please do specify the problem in an edit to your question, or in a comment if it's very short.

Comment: I did edit your answer, so I guess if you accept it the right query will show up at the top... The edit was just to add WHERE s1<>s2 and DISTINCT before connections. Otherwise they repeat. Thank you for your help!